# If clause behaves same using assignment operators as it does using equal operator

Tags: c, if-statement, equality, assignment-operator

Here is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
void main ()  
{  
      double pi = 3.1415926535;   
      int a = 1;  
      int i;    
      for (i=0; i < 3; i++) 
            if (a = cos(pi * i/2)) 
                  printf("% d", 1);  
            else printf("%d", 0); 
}
```

the line `if (a = cos(pi * i/2))` performs assignment operation and then checks the condition. So in that way the output should always be 1 as the assignment operation is always performed. But here the output comes `10 1`. Hence i think i got it wrong. Why is the output is `10 1` and not `111`? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `=` is the assignment operator. The compiler should be warning you, did you ignore the warning? Well, don't!

Second, you cannot compare floating point numbers reliably, and `cos()` will return such a number, so perhaps

```
if (a == (int) cos(pi * i / 2)) ...
```

can do it.

Also,

```
printf("% d", 1);
```

should be

```
printf("%d", 1);
/*       ^ no space here */
```

and really,

```
printf("1\n");
```

Comment: What i want to know is why the output is `101`?

Comment: Now you know how to find out, don't you think it's better?

Answer (score 1):

The if expression evaluates to the assigned value of a.  In this case, since a is declared as an int, it will truncate, so any value strictly less than 1 will evaluate to `0` - i.e. false.  Since `cos(x)` is always between `-1` and `1`, the only time you will enter the if block is if `x` is `0` or a multiple of pi (when `cos(x)` will evaluate to exactly `1` or `-1`).

Answer (score 1):

First understand that the if block will execute for every non zero value like -2,-3,234,1,-9999
but for value 0 the block will not execute.
So coming to your code,

The for loop runs three times 
i = 0, 1, 2

for i = 0 : if block will execute

```
cos(pi * i/2) => cos(pi* 0/2) => cos(0) => 1
if(a = cos(pi * i/2)) => if(a = 1)  => if(1)
```

for i = 1: if block will not execute

```
cos(pi * i/2) => cos(pi * 1/2) => cos( pi/2 ) => 0
if(a = cos(pi * i/2)) => if(a = 0) => if(0)
```

for i = 2 : if block will execute

```
cos(pi * i/2) => cos(pi * 2/2) => cos( pi )) => -1
if(a = cos(pi * i/2)) => if(a = -1) => if(-1)
```